# Continuous random variables with joint density function

Tags: random-variables, density-function

> Given that X, Y are continuous random variables with joint density function

$$f_{x,y}=x-y+1$$
And:
$$0 \leq x \leq 1$$
$$0 \leq y \leq 1$$

Need to calculate this:
$$P(y\geq \frac{1}{4}|x=\frac{1}{4})$$

How can I prove that?
I tried this:
$$\frac{P(y\geq \frac{1}{4},x=\frac{1}{4})}{P(x=\frac{1}{4})}$$

And after that I draw the domain (desmos.com):
[image]

finally I tried to make Integral and I got zero...

Comment: I can't see how (continued-fractions) tag is related to this question.

Comment: @Emre You're right, thank you.

Comment: Prove what? Do you mean "calculate"?

Comment: @probablyme Yes.

Comment: You can't use that formula, as $P(x=\frac 14)=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will need the conditional density of $Y$ given $X$. Notice that 
$$f_X(x) = \int_0^1 f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,dy = x+\frac{1}{2}.$$

Thus, we have that
$$f_{Y|X}(y|x) = \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_X(x)} = \frac{x-y+1}{x+1/2}.$$

Finally, we have
$$P(Y\geq 1/4|X = 1/4) = \int_{1/4}^1 f_{Y|X}(y|1/4)\,dy = \int_{1/4}^1\frac{1/4-y+1}{1/4+1/2}\,dy = \frac{5}{8}$$

Answer (score 3):

Let's use definitions. By definition,
$$
\mathbb{P}\left.\left(Y\geq\frac{1}{4}\right|X=\frac{1}{4}\right)=\int_{1/4}^1 f_{Y|X}(y|1/4)dy,
$$
where $f_{Y|X}$ is the conditional PDF, which is (by definition)
$$
f_{Y|X}(y|x)=\frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_{X}(x)},
$$
where $f_Y$ is the marginal PDF of $Y$, which is (by definition)
$$
f_X(x)=\int_0^1 f_{X,Y}(x,y)dy.
$$
Please complete the remaining integral calculations yourself.