# Joint density function of $T_1,T_2$ and expectation of $E[T_1 ^2 +T_2 ^2 ]$

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, expectation, uniform-distribution

> Given that $T_1,T_2$ are random variables representing the useful life (in
>   hours) of two electrical appliance.

The joint probability function of two variables distributed uniformly
in the domain of:

$$0\leq t_1\leq t_2 \leq L$$ ($L$ a positive  constant )

I need to prove that the Joint density function of $T_1,T_2$ is equal to  $\frac{2}{L^2}$.

And to calculate the expectation of $$E\left[T_1 ^2 +T_2 ^2 \right]$$

I'd like to know how to begin with this question?

Thank you.

Comment: Sorry but your probability questions are, as a rule, appallingly lacking of personal input. Are you in possession of, and using, some notes on the subject?

Comment: @Did This is a question I received from my academic tasks and I do not know how to start, I did not edit them and there is no backstory.
I do not understand the problem.

Comment: @LifeOfPai : I've posted an answer below that might tell you where to start.  You need to finish it by computing some integrals. $\qquad$

Comment: And THAT is the problem. By the way, do you think receiving here will make you "understand the problem"? You already tried that with your previous questions, with limited success it seems... (Let me note that you do not even answer the question in my comment.)

Comment: It's really hard to try to give you help because "I do not understand the problem" is so vague. There are dozens of things that can block you from understanding the problem. And doing the problem for you does not seem productive because you might still miss the point and come back with similar difficulties.

Comment: Typo: please replace "do you think receiving here" by "do you think that receiving full answers here"...

Comment: For example, did you understand anything at all from the answer you accepted [there](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1831665/)? If you did, this is odd because that question is definitely more sophisticated than the present one. If you did not, where are we going?

Comment: I'm really not looking for full answers, I do not know what you all are talking like this. I am trying to resolve the questions and do not know how to to approach it, it is not at all the same questions, that there's a double integral or density function that does not mean that all the same questions.

Comment: @LifeOfPai : If you don't understand the problem, you could say in the question you post that you don't understand the problem. $\qquad$

Answer (score 1):

$$
\operatorname{E}(T_1^2+T_2^2) = \iint\limits_\text{domain} (t_1^2 + t_2^2) f(t_1,t_2)\, d(t_1,t_2)
$$
where $f$ is the joint density function.  To say that the pair $(T_1,T_2)$ is uniformly distirbuted in the domain means that $f$ is constant in the domain.  Thus the expected value is
$$
\operatorname{E}(T_1^2+T_2^2) = \iint\limits_\text{domain} (t_1^2 + t_2^2)  c \, d(t_1,t_2)
$$
where the constant $c$ must be so chosen that
$$
\iint\limits_\text{domain} c\,d(t_1,t_2) = 1.
$$
The domain is defined by $$0 \le t_1 \le t_2 \le L.$$  Either of the double integrals above can be written as an iterated integral in either of two ways.

- First look at $$ \int_0^L \cdots \, dt_1 $$ i.e. $t_1$ goes from $0$ to $L$.  Then for any particualr value of $t_1$ between $0$ and $L$, the other variable $t_2$ goes from $t_1$ to $L$, so we have $$ \int_0^L \left( \int_{t_1}^L \cdots \, dt_2  \right) \, dt_1. $$
- Now look at $$ \int_0^L \cdots \, dt_2 $$ since $t_2$ goes from $0$ to $L$, but then for any fixed value of $t_2$, the other variable $t_1$ goes from $0$ to $t_2$, and we have $$ \int_0^L \left( \int_0^{t_2} \cdots \, dt_1 \right) \, dt_2 $$

Either approach will give the same answer.